# Facebook Landing page is not letting me click on it after Like it

Tags: facebook

I have a landing page that works when people click on it and they can go back to it after they like it , but when I try do do that on my own page it jumps me right back to the wall! I have removed the page,put it back on still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have a page tab app correct?  If so, go into your page settings and set that page tab app as the default one to be loaded.  Of course, if you're an admin of the page, that setting is ignored, so you will have to test with a non-admin account. Also make sure that the app you have set as the default page tab is also a public app.